# Find string in iframe within parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to trigger function if string found in iframe within parent page ?

I need to alter this to work with string and not element ID:

```
if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('mystring'))
{
document.getElementById('Search').style.display = 'block';}
```

Comment: By string found, do you mean an element with that `id` was found, or simply that strings exists on the page?

Comment: simply that string exist on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
var found = source.search("searchString");
```

you can also use `source.indexOf("searchstring") != -1`